# tidhttp: weird SSLv3_READ_BYTES error (with directly set up TLSv1_2 connection)

Tags: delphi, http, ssl, openssl, indy

Simple code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  //var
  //h: tIdHTTP;
  //SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  h.IOHandler := SSL;
  SSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  SSL.SLLOptions.SSLVersion := [sslvTLSv1_2]; //must be set automatically after SetMethod, but just to be sure
  h.Get('https://www.deviantart.com/users/login');
end;
```

That simple code gives me an error:

> Error connecting with SSL.
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I use Delphi XE3 and OpenSSL 1.0.2b libs.
I can't figure it out, looking into sources, there is strings in connection initiation that disable not used versions:

```
if not (sslvSSLv2 in SSLVersions) then begin
  SSL_CTX_set_options(fContext, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
end;
if not (sslvSSLv3 in SSLVersions) then begin
  SSL_CTX_set_options(fContext, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
end;
if not (sslvTLSv1 in SSLVersions) then begin
  SSL_CTX_set_options(fContext, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1);
end;
```

But sslv3 operations still getting in somehow. Doesn't look like a component's bug. Something library internal, or indy doesn't consider something when setting up parameters?

Or it's actually me, who didn't notice something important?
I really hope I don't need to go through a hell named "indy components update".

Test on (tried all methods including TLS1.2) `https://www.deviantart.com/users/login`

```
Resolving hostname www.deviantart.com.
Connecting to 54.230.96.81.
Handshake Start: before/connect initialization
Connect Loop: before/connect initialization
Connect Loop: SSLv3 write client hello A
fatal Read Alert: handshake failure
Connect Failed: SSLv3 read server hello A
ERROR: Error connecting with SSL.
error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

- for SSL3 and TLS1/1.1/1.2 result is identical;
- for SSLv23 answers SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure;
- for SSLv2 doesn't answer;

Test on similar resource (TLS1.2 ONLY) `https://files.yande.re/image/da9afa6d9ca43a9f154fad69f76adb85.jpg`

```
Resolving hostname files.yande.re.
Connecting to 5.39.10.56.
Handshake Start: before/connect initialization
Connect Loop: before/connect initialization
Connect Loop: SSLv3 write client hello A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read server hello A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read server certificate A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read server key exchange A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read server done A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 write client key exchange A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 write finished A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 flush data
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read server session ticket A
Connect Loop: SSLv3 read finished A
Handshake Done: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Connect Exit: SSL negotiation finished successfully
```

My WireShark tests:

- Indy: `http://imgur.com/BZ84Cl3` (response is handshake failure);
- Firefox: `http://imgur.com/pkYJvnO` ;
- Response to Firefox request: `http://imgur.com/M9ni3TV` ;

Comment: TLS1 is basically just an extension of SSL3. OpenSSL implements TLS1 inside of its SSL3 routines.

Comment: You can easily try newer versions of Indy if you add the Indy source directories to the project search path, and create the component dynamically. See also: [TIdHTTP now creates a default SSLIOHandler when requesting an HTTPS url](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20141222.DE.aspx)

Comment: mjn, thanks for a tip, didn't think about it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

*alert handshake failure* means the initial handshake is failing on the server side, so it sends an alert to notify your client before then closing the connection.  You probably did not setup a compatible certificate or cipher suite that the server is expecting.  Or maybe the server simply does not support TLS 1.2.  Try using TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 instead.  Also, you can try using OpenSSL's own `s_client` tool to debug connection problems until you figure out the correct settings, and then apply them to Indy as needed.  Or, use Wireshark to look at the actual handshake and see at which stage it is failing.

Comment: I hear you. Ofc I tried every accessible method, too. And also my browser definitely using TLS 1.2 encryption for it (according to a page security data).
There is another resource with a similar base (file server, not ui one):
https://files.yande.re/image/da9afa6d9ca43a9f154fad69f76adb85.jpg
It stopped working after poodle panic started, but an update on OpenSSL lib helped with it. Not with deviantart, tho. Basing on my browser's data, it uses the same encryption method for both resources. So, I think I should look into ciphers at a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a handshake problem this morning, comparing the wireshark logs of google chrome (which worked fine) and my application (with handshake problems). 
It turned out I had to enable the "signature_algorithms" extension.

However, I use SecureBlackBox (and not indy and openssl) because I had to dynamically load a client certificate, but maybe this can help you (compare and debug it with wireshark!).

Comment: Alas, it's not my case. Indy uses signature_algorithms, marking all signatures in it (from SHA1+RSA/DSA/ECDSA to SHA512).
Trying to figure out if another extensions can cause a problem (like heartbeat extension that used in indy's requests, but not in browser's), or something missing. It's gonna be a lot of pain playing with DLL flags T_T. Cipher list is identical with a browser ATM.